# is every positive real cyclotomic number the norm of a cyclotomic?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $a>0$ be a real cyclotomic number. Is it always possible to solve in cyclotomics the equation $X\overline{X}=a$ ?

Equivalently, one might want to express $a$  as a sum of squares of two real cyclotomics. It is well-known that one square is not always enough.

(If two squares are not enough, then, is there an upper bound?).

**Edit**: $a$ is not only positive, but totally positive (otherwise the answer is No).

Comment: The number $X\bar X$ is totally positive (any of its Galois conjugates is positive). Thus any $a$ which is positive but not totally positive would be a counterexample, e.g. $a=\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: my $a=\sum_{k=1}^m b_k\overline{b}_k$, $b_k$ cyclotomic. Is $a$ totally positive? (References on the topic would be much appreciated, too)

Comment: For the sum of squares, if $i$ is in the field, then $a=\left(\dfrac{a+1}{2}\right)^2+\left(i\dfrac{a-1}{2}\right)^2$. I'd check "A Historical View of the Pythagoras Numbers of Fields" by D. Leep

Comment: Your $a$ is totally positive, because it is the sum of totally positive elements.

Comment: a square with $i$ in it is not real.

Comment: yes, indeed, $a$ is totally positive, by a bit of Artin-Schreier theory.

Comment: You don't need Artin-Schreier theory. If you conjugate $a$ by $\sigma$, all the $b_k$'s get conjugated by $\sigma$, because complex conjugation commutes with $\sigma$. Then use that $z\bar z$ is positive for every nonzero $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: If $X_0$ is a solution then all other solutions are given by $X=X_0 \cdot (t-i)/(t+i)$ with $t \in \mathbb{Q}^{\mathrm{ab}} \cap \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @VictorOstrik - $\sqrt{2}=\zeta_8+1/\zeta_8$. In general, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/282779/39797

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $a$ is a totally positive real cyclotomic number, then it is a sum of two squares of real cyclotomic numbers.

It suffices to check that the equation $x^2+ y^2 - a z^2=0$ has solutions in real cyclotomic numbers. It has solutions in a particular real cyclotomic number field $F$ if it has solutions everywhere locally. This equation has solutions locally if and only if the quaternion algebra $(a,-1)$ splits locally.

First take the field $F$ generated by $a$. If we adjoin to $F$ a sufficiently large totally real extension of the field of $2$-power roots of unity (sufficiently large depending on the set of ramified places of this quaternion algebra), producing a field $K$, then every ramified place $v$ of this quaternion algebra will not be totally split in $K$; because $K/F$ is a Galois extension of degree a power of $2$, this implies that the quaternion algebra splits over $K_v$, and so the equation has solutions locally over $K_v$, thus solutions over $K$.

---

How sufficiently large?

For $v$ an odd prime with residue field $q_v$, it suffices to adjoin the totally real part of the $2^n$th roots of unity for the minimum $n$ such that $q_v^2 \neq 1 \mod 2^n$. To obtain this, it suffices to have $2^n \geq q_v^2$.

An odd prime $v$ only ramifies if it divides the numerator or denominator of $a$, in which case $q_v$ divides the norm of the numerator or denominator, so it suffices to have $2^n$ at least the max of the norms of the numerator and denominator squared.

To handle the even primes $v$, we need to ensure that the image of the inertia group of $2$ acting on the totally real part of field of the $2^n$th roots of unity is strictly larger than the image of the inertia group of $2$ acting on $F$. Since the image of the inertia group acting on the real part of the field of $2^n$th roots of unity is of order the degree $2^{n-2}$, it suffices to take $2^{n-2}> \deg F$.

So it suffices to take $2^n > \max( Na_1^2, Na_2^2, 4 \deg F)) $ with $Na_1, Na_2$ the norms of the numerator and denominator.  We can achieve this with $2^n \leq 2 \max( Na_1^2, Na_2^2, 4 \deg F)$, which is an extension of $F$ of degree $\leq ( Na_1^2/2, Na_2^2/2, 2\deg F)$.

Comment: @GHfromMO The places themselves are not totally split, which is what makes the quaternion algebra split.

Comment: "locally" - is it $p$-adic localisation, or something quite different?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Yes, $p$-adic, except that we need to localize at places $v$ of $F$, i.e. we write $F \otimes \mathbb Q_p$ as a product of fields and check that there exist solutions in each of those. (We would have to do the same thing with $F \otimes \mathbb R$, but the totally positive criterion guarantees that there exist solutions.)

Comment: @GHfromMO Yeah, I was a bit lazy when writing this answer. First, there is not a unique quadratic extension, but rather more than one. For $v$ odd, we will get the unramified one. The idea is this: Frobenius at $v$ acts on the $2^n$th roots of unity by raising to the exponent $q$. Choose $n$ large enough that $q^2$ is not congruent to $1$ mod $2^n$, and it will follow that Frobenius does not act by raising to the exponent $1$ or $-1$. Since complex conjugation acts by $-1$, Frobenius is not in the group generated by complex conjugation, and thus acts nontrivially on the real part.

Comment: Sure, and I said "unramified", not "ramified". A divison algebra of degree $n^2$ over a local field contains the unique unramified degree $n$ field extension of the local field. This field extension is generated by a root of unity, and it splits the division algebra. Thanks for the additional details! I will digest them after I get some sleep, although I see now what you had in mind.

Comment: @GHfromMO Sounds good - I may try to work on my reading skills...

Comment: Thanks for a deep answer (for me at least it would take a lot of time to verify it in detail, I never had a chance to proporly learn number theory).

Interestingly, this does imply that every unitary representation of a finite group can be written over cyclotomics, something that is not (widely - at least I don't  know a reference to such a result) known.

Any chance to have a meaningful upper bound on the needed extension degree?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Any irreducible representation of a finite group $G$ can be defined over $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_{N})$ with $N = |G|$; this is a theorem of Brauer from 1945. That's also clearly best possible in general, since one can take $G = \mathbf{Z}/N \mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: I am talking about unitary representations, i.e. ones where $g^{-1}=g^*$ for any group element $g$. That's where square roots and norms start to matter.

Comment: if you like an analogue with real representations it is akin to restricting to orthogonal representations in the real case.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik My edit gives an effective bound.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik If $V$ is an (absolutely irreducible) representation of $G$ over $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_N)$, can't you simply choose any Hermetian form $\langle x,y \rangle$ and then define $\langle x,y \rangle^{\mathrm{new}} = \sum_{g \in G} \langle gx,gy \rangle$?

Comment: naturally, you always preserve a Hermitean form, but only if the matrix of this form is $I$ you get $gg^*=I$.

Comment: @user175951 - I published https://www.ams.org/journals/ert/2021-25-31/S1088-4165-2021-00587-X - where I avoid using this answer, but perhaps it ought to be explored further.